# Add 0 to a data.table where ending 0 were omitted

Tags: r, data.table

I found out that in my raw data I have some fields which are continuously following the consumption of pellets. However, when the number was ending in 0, the zero was omitted and hence I would like to go back and fix this. This is how my data looks like

```
accumulatoin_calc <- as.data.table(read.table('pellet_data.csv', header = FALSE, sep = ";"))     
head(accumulatoin_calc[,.(Date_Hour_PC_EEST, Pellets_used_kilograms)])
         Date_Hour_PC_EEST Pellets_used_kilograms
    1: 2016-01-03 09:37:16                      19348
    2: 2016-01-03 09:37:21                      19349
    3: 2016-01-03 09:37:26                      1934
    4: 2016-01-03 09:37:31                      19341
    5: 2016-01-03 09:37:36                      19342
    6: 2016-01-03 09:37:41                      19343
```

I have written some script, which goes trough my data and checks if 19349/1934 is higher than 1 and different than 0, that there is something wrong there. The number of digits in the difference, would actually tell us how many zeros are missing. E.g. in this case 19349/1935 = 9.999483, which means only one zero is missing. If the number was 99.0082 it means we have omitted 2 zeros.

```
for(j in 2:nrow(accumulatoin_calc)) {
        if( accumulatoin_calc$Pellets_used_kilograms[j-1] != 0 & (accumulatoin_calc$Pellets_used_kilograms[j]/accumulatoin_calc$Pellets_used_kilograms[j-1]) > 1 ){
                digits = nchar(trunc(floor(accumulatoin_calc$Pellets_used_kilograms[j]/accumulatoin_calc$Pellets_used_kilograms[j-1])))
                for(i in 1:nchar(trunc(digits))) {
                        accumulatoin_calc$Pellets_used_kilograms[j] <- as.numeric(paste0(accumulatoin_calc$Pellets_used_kilograms[j], 0))
                        cat("\nTransforming row ", j, " out of ", nrow(accumulatoin_calc), " rows where 0s are omitted in the original file.")
                }
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, this script seems rather slow and maybe not so effective as my data has about 10 million data points. Would you be able to suggest more effective and faster way of doing this.

Comment: Hi, I have used the read.table function. My file separator is ";". Actually, even in the file opened in excel the 0 is not present. I guess the software generating those csv is just omitting the zeros. I have also edited the post, with how I read the data.

Comment: you can use `stringr` function `str_pad`